# Defining static methods with class as parameter

Tags: c++, static, static-methods

I've recently seen in the source code of a third party library I'm using, something like this:

```
class A
{

public:
    A();
    ~A();

    static bool executeOperation(const A& a);
};
```

Why a class should declare a static method with itself as a parameter??
Why not simply define something like:

```
bool executeOperation() const;
```

Are there some specific cases where a static function (with the class itself as a parameter) is better suitable despite of "traditional" class method?

Comment: Interfacing with C-code is a good example. If a C function takes a pointer to a function in order to call it later. It doesn't know about the implicit **this** argument. This can be solved by creating a static function which takes an explicit pointer to an object of that class. Although it doesn't work with references, and the function does not need to be a class member at all unless it calls private/protected methods.

Comment: It is also conceivable the function address is being stored somewhere for lookup+execution later for a given object, and the author of the suspect code was a unaware how `operator .*` and `operator ->*` work with a pointer-to-memfn.

Comment: Looking at how it's used and what it does usually provides some clues.

Comment: that parameter is an **instance**, not a class.